# Horizontally center children in table td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to horizontally center children in td. I want textarea and button to be aligned horizontally. How can I achieve that?

```css
table th, table td{
    padding:10px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  
    <tr>
        <td>
          <textarea rows="1">Lorem ipsum dolor</textarea>
          <button type="button" >Copy</button>
          
        </td>
   </tr>
   
</table>
```

Comment: Just use `textarea, button {vertical-align: middle}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend flexbox as it can mess with table structure/styling when having multiple columns. Try `vertical-align: middle;` instead.

```css
table th, table td{
    padding:10px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
table button, table textarea {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
  
    <tr>
        <td>
          <textarea rows="1">Lorem ipsum dolor</textarea>
          <button type="button" >Copy</button>
          
        </td>
   </tr>
   
</table>
```

Comment: He specify horizontally center, not vertically

Answer (score -1):

`margin: auto;` usually center horizontally block element.

```css
table th, table td{
  padding:10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

td > *{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <textarea rows="1">Lorem ipsum dolor</textarea>
      <button type="button" >Copy</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```